# Onepage Checkout Broken 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, prototype-js

I've seen this issue arise in many different threads but somehow none of the potential fixes have managed to work for me.

I've tried the popular:

```
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

add id to fieldset

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

But unfortunately this didn't want to work.

If you add a product to the cart from this website and proceed to the onepage checkout the website doesn't seem to load the first available option, be it 'Checkout Options' if you're a guest or 'Billing Address' if you're signed into an account on the website.

I was wondering whether anyone would have any other clues as to why it wouldn't work?

I have a hunch that it *may* be Prototype conflicting.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share error messages (from Chrome Developer tools) and other information to replicate or understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to include the site URL. http://dancersboxecom.safetechhosting.co.uk/